# My Resources are being loaded under https and not http

Tags: redirect, asp.net-core, https

I am using Asp.Net Core on Raspberry Pi and using NGINX as my server.

In my view: I have these (etc):

```
<script src="~/js/Messanger.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

But it is being served (and failing to serve) as

```
https://192.168.0.12/js/Messanger.js
```

I have tried using the full path (as I know the IP)

```
<script src="http://192.168.0.12/js/Messanger.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

My opening page is being served as http.

I have disabled the SSL in my project settings.

I have commented out: app.UseHttpsRedirection(); in startup.cs and have changed:

```
 "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
```

to

"applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"

in LaunchSettings.json (though I understand this is not deployed in release).

In my config for default for nginx on my Rpi I have:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

location /MyServer/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  http;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Path   /MyPath;
}
```

Comment: You might have applied HSTS on this app or some other site running on localhost previously. HSTS prevents SSL downgrade, so once HSTS has been registered on a domain (even if it's localhost), only HTTPS will be allowed, and the browser will automatically redirect to HTTPS if an HTTP request is attempted. Each browser has a different methodology for modify HSTS presets for sites, so you'll need to search for your specific browser for instructions.

Comment: @ChrisPratt interesting.  I just used several browsers and all have the same issue,  Upgrading to https.  So, it must seem I would need to get a ssl certificate for my Raspberry Pi? So, Each Pi would need a certificate? Am i reading that right?  Thanks

Comment: No. Check the HSTS settings in each browser first. There's usually a list somewhere in the browser of sites that have HSTS applied, and you can simply remove localhost from that list. However, it may be better to just go ahead and use HTTPS and not have to worry about it. For that, you just need a certificate per domain, so one cert for localhost is enough. You'll obviously need to do self-signed because localhost isn't a real domain you could register with an actual CA. Then, you'd simply need to add it to the trusted store of any client machines.

Comment: @ChrisPratt thanks for the info.  whilst I could work out and change the HSTS for my browser I would not be able to do that for anyone else viewing my site served from Pi int their browser. so, https is the way to go I guess. thank